# Run script relative to file location, not command line location in node

Tags: node.js

I'm not sure exactly what to call what I'm trying to do, but I have a node script that accesses a folder (./commands relative to the script file), but when I run the script from somewhere other than the folder, it is unable to find ./commands.

I.e. when I'm in the folder with the script in it, `./commands` refers to \script-folder\commands, but when I'm on the desktop, the script looks in Desktop\commands and finds nothing.

Is there any way to tell the script to run relative to its own folder, or do I just have to hard-code the full location of the commands folder in the script?

Comment: could you add how you read the `./commands` folder?

Comment: how do you run the script ?

Answer (score 0):

./ means current working directory. you can check with pwd command.
You can use `path.join(__dirname,yourpath);`